# помогите с решение в php или C++

Tags: php, java, python, c++, алгоритм

Работа светофора запрограммирована таким образом: с начала каждого часа, **в течении трех минут** горит *зеленый* сигнал, следующие **две минуты** горит *красный*, дальше в течении **трех минут** - *зеленый* и т. д. Вам нужно разработать программу, которая по введенному числу определяла какого цвета сейчас горит сигнал.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Каждые 5 минут ситуация повторяется. Так?

Значит, берем количество минут после целого часа, находим остаток от деления на 5. Если это 0, 1 или 2 - значит, зеленый, иначе - красный.

Запрограммировать-то сами, надеюсь, сможете?

Comment: Ну да, с секундами моё решение несколько усложнится))

Comment: я тоже так решал ,но ваш ответ увидел после...

Answer (score 2):

Вот такое рабочее решение на двойку зайдёт)

```
function solve($minutes) {
    [$a, $b] = array_map(fn($x) => (int)"$x"[strlen($x)-1], [$minutes+1, $minutes+2]);
    return $a === 0 || $a === 5 || $b === 0 || $b === 5 ? 'red' : 'green';
}

for ($i = 0; $i < 15; ++$i) {
    $result = solve($i);
    echo "$i: {$result}\n";
}
```

*Если убедишь препода, что ты просто презираешь деление, то можно и тройку =)*